# How can only the Edge browser be having trouble resolving specific domains of Google?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm using Microsoft Edge 39.14986.1000.0 (EdgeHTML 15.14986) and though I didn't have a problem at one point with this windows 10 release I have, through restarts, found that it will not resolve or load google.com youtube.com and multiple other Google domains like gmail.com.

This is odd to me because I can use the command window to ping them. I can't type in their ips to the address bar either; I think it gets a valid 302 to www.google.com from  216.58.193.78 and then shows the "Hmm, we can't reach this page. Try this Make sure you’ve got the right web address: https://www.google.com." message.

It's difficult for me to debug since it appears most other programs are not having issues, I've cleared the cache and cookies on Edge, which further claims it has no extensions installed at all.

Lastly this is distinct from throwing a certificate verification error, so:
How could one app be behaving like it's hijacked or broken while other applications (chrome, cmd/ping/tracert) are acting like there's no issue here?
Is there a known issue, a resolution? Windows Defender and the monthly anti-malware thingy haven't complained before or after this started happening.

Comment: I'm told this is specific to windows 10 build 14986

Comment: If in doubt about what Edge is actually doing (like perhaps not really trying to connect at all), check with Wireshark. Because of HTTPS, you can’t look inside the requests, but you can at least check the network activity.

Comment: Did you try disabling the "Page Prediction" and the "SmartScreen" protection ? I found in the past that these can cause some really weird interference on perfectly normal web-sites.

Comment: Wireshark is too heavy in this case. I recommend Fiddler.

Comment: @FleetCommand Fiddler will not produce the same results. It will no longer be Edge making the actual connection to the target site. It simply cannot be used to diagnose what’s going on.

Comment: @DanielB I am aware. Actually that's my purpose. Think about it: What would be the source of the problem if a connection fails without Fiddler but succeeds with it? (Hint: The remote computer cannot tell the difference between the two.)

Comment: @Tonny I can confirm that with the settings of Page Prediction and SmartScreen turned off, the behavior is the same for google.com.

Comment: @DanielB It appears to query dns for google, get a response, do a get request for http://google.com/ receive a 302 to https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl Then it asks a server about google.com gets a response that it's Equifax registered signed by GeoTrust. Then is sent `CertificateServer Key Exchange, Server Hello Done`. I see that followed by some QUIC protocol encrypted back and forth, and some other back and forth in TLSv1.2... but I kind of lost track when it went encrypted, so, yeah it's trying to talk to Google pretty much.